# Cloudflare Page Rule Redirection Problem with Subdomains

Tags: redirect, dns, cloudflare, vercel

I've set up a Page Rule in Cloudflare to direct subdomains of my domain to specific URLs. The Page Rule has the following configuration:

```
URL Pattern: www.*.mydomain.io/*
Forwarding URL (Status Code: 301 - Permanent Redirect)
Destination URL: https://www.mydomain.io/test/$1/example
```

The Issue: The Page Rule functions correctly for most subdomains, except when accessing subdomains without the "www" prefix. To address this, I attempted to add another Page Rule as follows:

```
URL Pattern: *.mydomain.io/*
Forwarding URL (Status Code: 301 - Permanent Redirect)
Destination URL: https://mydomain.io/test/$1/example
```

However, when attempting to access a subdomain such as gopro.mydomain.io, it redirects to https://mydomain.io/test/www/example instead of the expected https://mydomain.io/test/gopro/example. Additionally, when accessing mydomain.io directly, it redirects to https://mydomain.io/test/www/example.

DNS Configuration: Here is my current DNS configuration:

```
A Records:
mydomain.io: 7X.7X.XX.XX

CNAME Records:
*.mydomain.io: mydomain.io
www.mydomain.io: cname.vercel-dns.com
```

How can I resolve this issue and enable the ability to access subdomains with or without the "www" prefix, redirecting them to the correct URLs?